# How to select parent components variant in styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

In `styled-components` we can add contextual styles using [component selector pattern](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components). But how do we select specific parents variants to contextually style the child component? For example, we have three components here, `Child`, `NoteWrapper`, and `Note`.

```
const Child = styled.div<{ editing?: boolean }>`
  ${props => props.editing && css`some styles`}
`

const NoteWrapper = styled.div<{ compact?: boolean }>`
  ${props => props.compact && css`some styles`}
`

const Note = styled.input`

/* How do I style this when Child is editing and NoteWrapper is compact */

`

const App = () => {
  return (
   <Child editing>
    <NoteWrapper compact>
     <Note/>
    </NoteWrapper>
   </Child>
  )
}

`
```

With plain CSS we could do something like this

```css
.child.editing .note-wrapper.compact .note {
  /* Contextual styles here */
}
```

I know I can easily use the `editing` and `compact` variables and pass it to the `Note` component. However, it would be difficult to do so if components are highly nested.

My question is how do I style `Note` when `Child` is `editing` and `NoteWrapper` is `compact` in `styled-components` selector pattern?

I don't think we can do something like this in `styled-components` in some way? Can we?

```
const Note = styled.input`
 ${Child.editingClass} ${NoteWrapper.compactClass} & {
  /* The contextual styles here*/
 }
`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't access `editing` or `compact`, since they're props and aren't "propagated" in CSS. But you can achieve the same result using either classes or data attributes.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
  <Child data-editing={true}>
    <NoteWrapper data-compact={true}>
      <Note/>
    </NoteWrapper>
  </Child>
  )
}

const Child = styled.div`
`

const NoteWrapper = styled.div`
`

const Note = styled.input`
  ${Child}[data-editing="true"] ${NoteWrapper}[data-compact="true"] & {
    /* 
      Only applied when Child is editing and NoteWrapper is compact
    */
    color: red;
  }

`
```

Essentially, styled-components needs to produce valid CSS at the end of the day. `${Child}` will be replaced by the custom-generated classname, like `.sc-abc123`. And so the end result is `.sc-abc123[data-editing="true"]`, which is totally-valid CSS.

You could also use classes, which looks a bit tidier:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
  <Child className="editing">
    <NoteWrapper className="compact">
      <Note/>
    </NoteWrapper>
  </Child>
  )
}

const Child = styled.div`
`

const NoteWrapper = styled.div`
`

const Note = styled.input`
  ${Child}.editing ${NoteWrapper}.compact & {
    /* 
      Only applied when Child is editing and NoteWrapper is compact
    */
    color: red;
  }

`
```

I prefer to use data-attributes because it's clear that they're used for logical purposes, and not because `editing` is a CSS class with a bunch of styles. But that's a subjective preference, they both work equally well in terms of objective functionality :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This made it clear. I too prefer using data-attributes.

Comment: const UnorderedList = styled.ul`
        position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 &.active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 > li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 > li:nth-child(1) {
  ${UnorderedList}.active &{
   top: 50px;
  }
 }




I am trying to do this! list item top just won't change on active.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass the props to the `Note` component itself and do a similar logic check.

```
<Note
  compactEdit={editing && compact}
/>

const Note = styled.div`
  ${props =>
    props.compactEdit
      ? css`color: red;`
      : css`color: blue;`
    };
`;
```